# Looking for a subscriber list management system

Tags: plugin-recommendation, database, events, list, subscription

Is there any plugin that enables the creation of forms and has a smart tool for subscribers (not site visitors who registered) database management?
I'm looking for a plugin that does that for a long time for different type of needs. For example, event subscription, workshops, courses etc.
I don't need an event/calendar tool, just forms. The emphasis not on the front end but on the ability to manage the subscriber lists in the back end.

Thanks

Comment: Subscribers are those who filled out a form? What is "a long time"? You named some of the different type of needs: event subscription, workshop, courses. How are those needs part of the plugin or aren't they?

Comment: Yes, subscribers are those who fill out the form. The different needs I mentioned here are just examples of client needs are came across in my projects.

Comment: The examples are meant to give you the idea of which type of activities the subscriptions are meant for.
A newsletter is another example. However, my main need here is not the mass email service, but the ability to view lists of emails (and other details) of people who subscribed.
If it's possible, an export to excel or in place sorting/filtering of those lists can be extremely useful.

Answer (score 2):

Even I placed a lot of questions back to your question, I would like to share the following idea:

This basically sounds to me that users are subscribing to a post (maybe of a custom post type and with a custom taxnomoy). So to replace the comment form with a subscription form and to use comment "subscriptions" as "post subscriptions". That for re-using the database.

Next to that, this would need some backend to handle daily jobs in the admin.

I'm not aware that any plugin is already offering this. But probably if you get a bit more flexible with your needs you can find some components you can mash-up into something what you're looking for without the need of much coding.

Comment: Thank you hakre. I will try to implement your idea regarding post types

Answer (score 2):

I've used cforms II for that in the past. It's way more than what you need, but it's really powerful, so it means only one plugin to implement the subscription, contact, and other forms within the site
http://www.deliciousdays.com/cforms-plugin/

Comment: Second the recommendation. Excellent plugin and fairly easy to extend.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a multi-faceted form suite, I'd take a strong look at Gravity Forms. It isn't free, but it's well worth the price.

Answer (score 1):

Check this. This plugin looks suitable for your requirements.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/g-lock-double-opt-in-manager/